# Nginx правильная конфигурация файла

Tags: nginx

Имеется dev сервер на Apache, все работает хорошо, но на production сервере установлен Nginx  и с ним возникли проблемы. Необходимо отсылать post ajax запрос на сервер к файлу index.php который находится в папке TEST. URL ajax запроса выглядит следующим образом /TEST/checkout/confirm так же передаются дополнительные параметры. На сервере мы принимаем запрос и обрабатываем

```
$app->post('/checkout/confirm', function () use ($app) {
....
}
```

Как настроить кофиг Nginx так чтоб он корректно отсылал пост запрос?

.htaccess из папки TEST

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Конфигурация Nginx

```
 server {
    listen   80;
    server_name easypay.bigbar.com;
    return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {    
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name easypay.bigbar.com www.easypay.bigbar.com;

    root /var/www/easypay.bigbar.com;
    index index.php;

    location / {

       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php ;

    rewrite ^/fb https://facebook.com/bigbardogbeds last;
        rewrite ^/freereturns /free-return.php last;
        rewrite ^/return-policy /return-policy2.php last;
        rewrite ^/orderconfirmation /orderconfirmation.php last;
        rewrite ^/pages/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php last;
        rewrite ^/pages/return-policy /return-policy2.php last;
        rewrite ^/collections/(accessories)$ /$1.php last;
        rewrite ^/collections/accessories/products/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php last;
        rewrite ^/products/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php last;

    }

    location /TEST {
    alias /var/www/easypay.bigbar.com/TEST;
#   index index.php;
#   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
#   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$request;
#   autoindex on;
    include fastcgi_params;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /TEST/index.php?$args;
    # To allow POST on static pages

    #rewrite ^/TEST /index.php last;
    }

    ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/easypay/easypay.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/easypay/easypay.key;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico)$ {
      expires 365d;
      log_not_found off;
      access_log off;
    }

    location ~ \.php(.*)$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-easypay.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

#   ssl on;

}
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос ваш .htaccess для апача.

Comment: в .htaccess никаких настроек нет

Comment: интерпретатор *php* каким образом вызывается? *nginx*-ом через интерфейс *cgi*? тогда приложите к вопросу, пожалуйста, секцию `server` *nginx*-а. внести исправления в вопрос можно, нажав [edit].

Comment: добавил config nginx

Comment: В проекте используется Slim framework

Comment: Не заметил  .htaccess в папке TEST. Добавил в сообщение. На сколько я понял все не существующие запросы отсылаются файлу index.php. Как подобное можно реализовать с помощью Nginx?

Answer (score 1):

В location TEST лучше отправлять запрос на cgi порт напрямую:

```
location /TEST {
    include fastcgi_params;

    try_files  $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-easypay.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

Так как nginx сам по себе не взаимодействует с php в вашей инсталяции, а значит ваш запрос просто не доходит до того, кем он должен быть выполнен